# To what extent does the GCC Runtime Library Exception cover macros, typedefs and functions?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, exceptions

Recently, I've had some trouble trying to get `std::thread` working with [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) g++. Considering that I don't want a dependency on [gthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Portable_Threads), I was wondering if I could use [thread.cc](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc.html) (and [cxxabi_forced.h](https://github.com/hjl-tools/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/cxxabi_forced.h)) with the following macro functions instead:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS 1
#define __gthread_t thrd_t
#define __gthread_create(a, b, c) thrd_create(a, (thrd_start_t)b, c)
#define __gthread_join thrd_join
#define __gthread_detach thrd_detach
#define __gthread_self thrd_current
#define __gthread_yield thrd_yield
```

However, as the [GCC Runtime Library Exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.html) states:

> use of source code generators and preprocessors need not be considered
>   part of the Compilation Process, since the Compilation Process can be
>   understood as **starting with the output of the generators or
>   preprocessors**.

This makes me think that in the first example, the whole code is now covered by GPLv3 due to some macros changing the code itself. So, I came up with another idea:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS 1
typedef thrd_t __gthread_t;
int __gthread_create(thrd_t *thr, void *func(void*), void *arg) {
    return thrd_create(thr, (thrd_start_t)func, arg);
}
int __gthread_join(__gthread_t thr, int *res) {
    return thrd_join(thr, res);
}
int __gthread_detach(__gthread_t thr) {
    return thrd_detach(thr);
}
__gthread_t __gthread_self(void) {
    return thrd_current();
}
void __gthread_yield(void) {
    thrd_yield();
}
```

In this line of code below, you can see that `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` was set to `1` just so that thread.cc would function properly.

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)
```

I assume this doesn't cause licensing problems. Can I use the last example in combination with non-GPLv3 compatible software? Is it true that the first example is completely covered by GPLv3?